# SaveFileDialog crash with exception code 0xc0000005

Tags: c#, .net, access-violation, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I have an issue with application in C#. When I try to call ShowDialog on SaveFileDialog object application crashes.
The code which causes crash is in try catch block, but since it crahses application I'm unable to get stack trace.

```
 try
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

            sfd.AddExtension = true;
            sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(this.title);
            sfd.Filter = "File type (" + ext + ")|*" + ext;
            sfd.FileName = Program.NormalizeTitle(this.title);

            DialogResult ds = sfd.ShowDialog(this);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

This is the error description:

```
Faulting application name: test.exe, version: 1.0.0.1, time stamp: 0x56585459
Faulting module name: wkscli.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce795a7 
Exception code: 0xc0000005 
Fault offset: 0x00001e8f 
Faulting process id: 0x%9 
Faulting application start time: 0x%10 
Faulting application path: %11 
Faulting module path: %12
```

Sometimes faulting module name is Ntshrui.dll.

This code works fine for years on any other machine. It happend on Windows 2008 R2 with .Net 2.0 and 4.0.
What could be the problem?

Comment: If you run you application in the debugger, where exactly does it fail?

Comment: On this line  DialogResult ds = sfd.ShowDialog(this); But I can not run in debugger cause it is in customer env.

Comment: `0xc0000005` is an access violation, i.e. an invalid (native) memory access. Could be really anything, even code could be the cause that has long completed execution when you call your stuff. But since you are getting it while dealing with the shell, it _could_ be a bad 3rd party shell extension. You can try to deactivate shell extensions with tools like [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and see if the error goes away.

Comment: 0xc0000005 is an Access violation error so check if you have read/write rights to your file.

Comment: You arent running this in a thread are you?

Comment: no thread.. just a form application

Comment: verify that the value obtained from NormalizeTitle is valid in terms of length and formatting... never know how "tolerant" those APIs are

Answer (score 2):

The exception code `0xc0000005` means access violation. As it happens when the save as dialog is displayed the exception could be caused by an Explorer shell extension.

Using **[Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)** from Sysinternals, or Nirsoft's [**ShellExView**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) you can see which shell extensions are installed on your system, and you can disable them one-by-one.

Comment: I will try that that way.

Comment: @john1020: And of course, always something to check is for corrupted system files, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833